# An error is raised when I use stat_compare_means

Tags: r, boxplot, p-value, ggpubr

I tried with R to add the "p" values on a boxplot, but an error is raised when I use  stat_compare_means. I looked quickly on google but I still do not understand ...

Here is the boxplot I try to display :

```
boxplot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Produit, y = P.cell.ouv)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(name ="Proportion de cellules vidées", limits=c(0,0.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name ="") +
  geom_text(data = myletters_df, aes(label = letter, y = 0.35 ), colour="black", size=5) +
  stat_compare_means( label.x = 0.7, method = "kruskal.test")
```

And here the error raised

```
> boxplot
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type quosure/formula. Defaulting to continuous.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type quosure/formula. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in validDetails.text(x) : 
  'pairlist' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: could you add some data? - try dput(head(data)) if to give us data representative of the problem.

Comment: structure(list(Produit = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c(...), class = "factor"), Sample = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c(...), class = "factor"), P.cell.ouv = c(0.13, ...), Nb.cell.reop = c(25L, 21L, 19L, 26L, 12L, 19L),  P.cell.reop = c(0.83, ...), Nb.cell.intact = c(1L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 16L, 16L), P.cell.intact = c(0.03, ...)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Hmmm, that's not working for some reason - gives me an `error in structure "..." used in incorrect context` error